# System Tray image not loading java

Tags: java

I have a program which when runs displays an icon in system tray. i am using the below code to display an icon in system tray area:

```
public static void showTrayIcon() {
        if (java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            st = java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray();

             image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(PongeeUtil.class.getClass().getResource("export.png"));



            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
                }
            };

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

            MenuItem defaultItem = new MenuItem("sdf");
            defaultItem.addActionListener(listener);
            popup.add(defaultItem);

            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo", popup);

            trayIcon.addActionListener(listener);
            try {
                st.add(trayIcon);

            } catch (AWTException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        } 
    }
```

When i call this method in my `main()` i got something in my system tray but icon is missing. i think image is not able to load. image is in the same package where my java files resides.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Where is `export.png` located within context to the source?  Consider using `ImageIO.read` to load images, it throws errors when it can't load them.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: image is in the same package where my java files are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> image is in the same package where my java files are

If you take a look at the JavaDocs for [`Toolkit#getImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage(java.lang.String)) you will find that it says...

> Returns an image which gets pixel data from the **specified file**

This is important.  You should also know that `getImage` loads the physical image in a background thread, which means if it fails to load the image, it will do so silently...

Okay.  The core problem is, once the image is placed within the context of the application (with the class files), it becomes, whats commonly known as, an embedded resource.

These resources can not be loaded via any means that requires access to a file on the file system.

Instead, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to load them, for example

```
image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(YourClass.class.getResource("/package/path/to/classes/export.png"));
```

Or more preferabbly...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(YourClass.class.getResource("/package/path/to/classes/export.png"));
image = new ImageIcon(img);
```

`ImageIO` will throw an `IOException` when it can't load the image for some reason, which gives you more diagnostic information to fix problems

nb:

- `YourClass` is you class which contains the `showTrayIcon` method...
- `/package/path/to/classes` is the package name under which the image is stored...

Comment: i am loading image using Class#getResource but no image. see my edit

Comment: And what is the package name that the class and image reside in?

Comment: And you only need `PongeeUtil.class.getResource`